# How to get datatable visible columns Index for save states in database

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatable, datatables

I want to get total visible columns name on button click to save states in the database.

Example - `colName - Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col8, Col9`

After saving the column name in the database, when user will come back to this table then he should be able to see only those columns which he had saved in the database.

> When user come back then columns which are showing with column name - Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col8, Col9

I found these function for column hide/show dynamically -

To show column `oTable.fnSetColumnVis(item, true,false);`

to hide column `oTable.fnSetColumnVis(item, false,false);`

## Conclusion

1. How can I get the total list of visible columns name in data table?
2. When the user will log in back, he should be able to get visible only those columns which he had saved last time?

Any input will be helpful thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`DataTable.columns().visible()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().visible())

**UPDATE**

Using [`columns().every( fn )`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().every())

```js
let dataTable = $('#example').DataTable({
  "colReorder": true,
  "columnDefs": [
    { "visible": false, "targets": [1] },
    { "visible": false, "targets": [4] },
    { "visible": false, "targets": [5] },
  ]
});

// let result = dataTable.columns().visible().reduce((a, v, i) => v ? [...a, i] : a, [])

// console.log(result)

dataTable.on('column-reorder', function() {
  console.clear();
  dataTable.columns().every(function(i) {
    this.visible() && console.log(i, this.header().innerHTML)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.5.1/css/colReorder.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.5.1/js/dataTables.colReorder.min.js"></script>


<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Numero</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>155555</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I update the question, can you please look into this? I want column name, not column index because I had implemented column re-ordering functionality on the same table so when user re-order column then that impacted on show/hide columns, so I want column name array.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the total list of visible columns in datatable?

Extending @Aswin Kumar answer

```
let dataTable = $('#example').DataTable({
  "columnDefs": [
    { "visible": false, "targets": [1] },
    { "visible": false, "targets": [4] },
    { "visible": false, "targets": [5] },
  ]
});

let result = dataTable.columns().visible().reduce((a, v, i) => v ? [...a, i] : a, [])

console.log(result) // Gives you index list of all the visible columns
```

> When user will login back, he should be able to get only those indexes
>   which he had saved last time?

This can be a bit tricky.

You need to save each column value in Database and on load of Table get those values and use them to show columns

something like this

```
table.columns( [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ] ).visible( false, false );
```

More [Detail here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().visible())

**Edit 1:**

Get all visible column Name and index.

```
function get_visible_columns() {
    //console.log(table);
   var all_columns = table.settings().init().columns;
    console.log('all_columns', all_columns);
    var visible_columns = [];
    for (var i in all_columns) {
        if (table.column(all_columns[i].name + ':name').visible()) {
            visible_columns.push(all_columns[i].name);
            console.log("index: "+i);
        }
    }

    alert(visible_columns.join(', '));
}
```

Index will be used to restore all visible columns

```
table.columns( [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ] ).visible( false, false );
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/crazzzy/3acbfre2/1/)

Comment: Hi @MyTwoCents, I had also implemented column re-ordering on the same table so that I want to save column name expect column index in the database. Can you suggest to me how we getting visible column name array and how to restore it when user back?

Comment: added detail to get column name